# Swing: setContentPane not refreshing the interface when called

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a problem with my applet: it doesn't refresh when I need it to.

I'm trying to switch from one interface screen to the other when I click on the button.

I have a

```
public class PixelRainEditorApp extends JApplet
```

and in the init

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createGUI();
    }
});
private void createGUI() {
    a = new A(this);
    this.setSize(800, 480);
}
```

Then I have 2 classes A and B that extend JPanel

```
public A(JApplet parent) {
   super(parent);
   setOpaque(true);
   setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   this.parent.setContentPane(this);
}
```

when I click on a button in view A

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if(TAG.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())){
      new B(this.baseParent);
   }
}
```

and B is the same as A but with different images

```
public B(JApplet parent) {
       super(parent);
       setOpaque(true);
       setBackground(Color.BLACK);
       this.parent.setContentPane(this);
    }
```

Now this works fine when I want to display A, but when I want to launch B when I click on a button in A, nothing happens.
Its only when I resize the window that B appears...
I tried to invalidate or repaint and various places in my applications but nothing happens

Any ideas ?

Jason

Comment: How do you add an instance of the class B?

Comment: Edited my question, I'm pretty sure its something so stupid :S

Comment: I don't think it is stupid, I had similar issues in the past and I am dead sure my code was correct. Try revalidate() method (if it is available), try different look & feel (I am not sure - I don't remember but I probably "fixed" my issues this way).

Comment: well I manged with revalidate, then I tried changing it in class A and guess what it works in B but not in A :P. I'll play around (I'm going to implement a view switcher so that all this gets centralized in on eplace)

Comment: The code posted is not only illogical, it would not even compile!  I suggest that for better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  One tip mentioned in the SSCCE document that is relevant to making a multi class SSCCE is to reduce the visibility of the panel classes A and B to default - so they can be included in the same source file.  I also strongly recommend you look at a CardLayout, since that is what I would naturally use for the effect you describe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add 
this.parent.revalidate();
this.parent.repaint(); 
in th end of your calls.

Comment: Yep it finally started working when I put the view switcher in place and was able to centralize the changes (I had a nightmare of threads/invok later/swingworker causing refresh problems).